# Scrollview not scrolling full Activity when it focus on editText when FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS is set

Tags: android, scrollview

I have an ImageView,2 EditTexts and a button vertically inside ScrollView with FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS is set. My problem is when I focus on edittext keyboard, hides edittexts and button, ScrollView doesn't scrollup to show edittexts and button. If I omit FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS flag, scrollview works fine. I tried android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" along with FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS set, no use.
Please help me